# Is it possible to display different colors depending on percentage completion in progress bar?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Hello Progress Experts!!!

I am trying to display the different colors based on percentage completion in progress bar like 
percentage 0% - 25% - Red , 25% - 50% - Yellow , 50% - 100% - Green Color.

The concern here is the following codes helps to provide percentage completion in FILL-IN box but I don't know how to give colors.

Note - Color should change and move gradually in FILL-IN box.
(like we usually see progress bar in the system while copy and paste into another folder).

I heard we can use .NET methods in progress. It would be better if possible using this.

This might be stupid question(move gradually ) or unviable in progress. Yeah! as you know keep asking question why or why not is good for get some knowledge.

Please throw a small lamp here which gives bright to the dark.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE I                  AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iPercentage        AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iComp              AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iRec               AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN
    I     = 0
    iComp = 0
    iRec  = 0
    iPercentage = 0.


/* Calculating Total records*/
FOR EACH <table> NO-LOCK:
    iRec = iRec + 1.
END.
/* Taking each records from the same table to update*/
FOR EACH <table> NO-LOCK:
  I = I + 1.

  IF I = 1 THEN DO:
     RUN UpdateRecord.p (INPUT <table>.<tablefield>)
     ASSIGN
        iComp =  iComp  + I.
        iPercentage  = 100 * (iComp / iRec).

     DO WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}:    
           ASSIGN
           /* fiProgress is FILL-IN */
           fiProgress:SCREEN-VALUE = STRING(iPercentage) + '%'.
           PROCESS EVENTS. 
     END.
     IF iPercentage = 100 THEN DO:
        MESSAGE "Record Updation Is completed".
     END.
     ELSE DO:
         I = 0
         NEXT.
     END.

  END.

END.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (...) color should change and move gradually (...)

If by gradually you would like a real gradient effect, you're out of luck using pure Progress. BGCOLOR only accepts the colors defined in the palette (1-15, unless you want to create your own dynamic new colors (which is possible, but would require some work).
You can, however, assign it to an ActiveX field (formerly known as OCX) using the RGB-VALUE function, but if you're going down that route, I bet you can probably find an ActiveX progress bar to use and eliminate the need to recreate the wheel. I'll take your question as a pure progress feature you'd like to add.

For the sake of code reusability and adaptation, which is the goal of this site, I decided to create something that can be independent from your posted code (if you'll allow me), but easily built into it.

So in this example you should have 2 fill-ins, one of them with NO-LABEL and on top of the first, at the exact same column and row coordinates.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE iCount AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iCalc  AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
REPEAT:
  ASSIGN fill-in-1:BGCOLOR = IF iCount = 0 THEN 12
                             ELSE IF iCount = 25 THEN 14
                             ELSE IF iCount = 50 THEN 2
                             ELSE IF iCount = 75 THEN 10
                             ELSE fill-in-1:BGCOLOR.
  ASSIGN iCount = iCount + 1.

  /* Calculate reduction and placement of white fill-in */
  ASSIGN iCalc = INT((100 - iCount) * fill-in-1:WIDTH / 100)
         fill-in-2:WIDTH = if iCalc <> 0 then iCalc else 0.1
         fill-in-2:COLUMN = fill-in-1:COLUMN + (fill-in-1:WIDTH - iCalc).

  IF iCalc = 0 THEN
     ASSIGN fill-in-2:VISIBLE = NO.
  /* /End calculation */

  ASSIGN fill-in-1:SCREEN-VALUE = STRING(iCount).
  IF iCount = 100 THEN LEAVE.
  PAUSE 0.2 NO-MESSAGE.
  PROCESS EVENTS.
END.
```

This snippet works by itself sleeping for 0.2 seconds so you can get the idea of what's going on. Remove the pause and replace iCount with your percentage and you should get what you are looking for. PROCESS EVENTS would be a good idea, but not necessary to have.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Shout out to my buddy Marlon Berkenbrock @marlonberkenbrock for bringing to my attention he got a zero width warning (which never showed to me due to my session configurations). The current version fixes that.

Comment: @bupereire - Thank you so much and let me test your edited codes and come back ASAP

Comment: @bupereire - I run your sample code and its looks like almost what i expected but the small issue is that BG-COLOR is fully covered into FILL-IN box but expected is should move gradually. As you said yeah! i am out of lucky using pure progress. Anyway you satisfied me. Tnx man . I am going to implement this

Comment: The second fill in decreasing in size should give the impression that the box is filling and not reveal that the fill-in-1 is always 100% filled in the back. Did you place the two fill ins on top of each other with fill-in-1 at the bottom?

Comment: yes i did that too. Tnk you so much for the satisfied answer for my question

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve this with fiProgress:BGCOLOR but color values in ABL GUI are pretty limited as they are limited to the color palate loaded at session start. You can, technically, overwrite them at runtime, but it's not a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

I found some other way for my question and could see bar moving gradually.
Thanks @bupereire for an idea.

Note - FILL-IN box width should be 1.00

```
      DEFINE VARIABLE iCount AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
      DEFINE VARIABLE iCalc  AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
      DO WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}:  
      REPEAT:    
      ASSIGN iCount = iCount + 1
             iCalc = INT(100 - iCount)
             fill-in-1:WIDTH = 1
             fill-in-1:WIDTH = (fill-in-1:WIDTH + iCount)
             fill-in-1:BGCOLOR = IF iCount < 25 THEN 4
                                 ELSE IF (iCount > 25 AND iCount < 50)  THEN 9
                                 ELSE IF (iCount > 50 AND iCount < 75) THEN 14
                                 ELSE IF (iCount > 75 AND iCount < 100) THEN 10
                                 ELSE fill-in-1:BGCOLOR.

      IF iCount = 100 THEN LEAVE.
      PAUSE 0.5 NO-MESSAGE.
      PROCESS EVENTS.
      END.
      END.
      END PROCEDURE.
```